# how fetch this url content by curl - php

Tags: php, curl

I want to fetch out content of this url: **http://www.freeproxylists.net/?s=rs**

I used this code:

```
<?php
$url = str_replace(' ', '%20', "http://www.freeproxylists.net/?s=rs");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36');

    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $action['cockie'] );

    $data['content'] = curl_exec($ch);
    $data['rescode'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $data['type'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $data['endurl'] = urldecode ( curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) );

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $data['content'];
?>
```

when I use a browser to open this url it show me main contents but with php curl give me a page with captcha code.

I sent all of headers that browser send to url by sockets too. but this time it gave me a page with captcha too. but why ??

Comment: Looks like *freeproxylists.net* is using a bot detection mechanism. If you open the page in the browser and look in the console, you'll see that it sends a request to `/h.php` with some parameters in a cookie.

Comment: please learn me how you detected this ?? I'm using google chrome but dont know how detect this in console

Comment: As yoavmatchulsky said, server checks cookies. So you have to set `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options.

Comment: @hindmost exactly what I must add to my sample code ??

Comment: @saeid Exactly - `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options). If you want more go here (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: @saeid look under the *Network* tab in the console (press F12 to open it, or right click on the page and select *Inspect Element*). Then reload the page